# How to make a button reappear in different place when clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button

I started to learn coding in Android studio few weeks ago. Now I'm trying to make an application which has 9 buttons, but you always see just one of them. When you click on visible button it should disappear and show another one and so on. 
This is what I've made so far:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button shownButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        shownButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        shownButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    public void buttonDisappear(View view){
        shownButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Random generatedNumber = new Random();
        int buttonNumber = generatedNumber.nextInt(10 - 0) + 10;
        String nextShownButton = "b"+String.valueOf(buttonNumber);
        int nextShownButtonId = getResources().getIdentifier(nextShownButton, "id", getPackageName());

        Button shownButton = (Button) findViewById(nextShownButtonId);
        shownButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}
```

In every button property "onClick" I set a function "buttonDisappear". Everything looks fine to me, no errors, but when I run the program and click on the first button (b1), application just stops. Can you tell me why it is happening and how can I fix it? Thank you.

UPDATE

**activity_main.xml**

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="buttonDisappear"
        android:text="@string/mygtukas"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:onClick="buttonDisappear"
        android:text="@string/mygtukas"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:onClick="buttonDisappear"
        android:text="@string/mygtukas"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:onClick="buttonDisappear"
        android:text="@string/mygtukas"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:onClick="buttonDisappear"
        android:text="@string/mygtukas"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:onClick="buttonDisappear"
        android:text="@string/mygtukas"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:onClick="buttonDisappear"
        android:text="@string/mygtukas"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="buttonDisappear"
        android:text="@string/mygtukas"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: change your `buttonDisappear(Button view)` to `buttonDisappear(View view)`

Comment: please post the stacktrace

Comment: Please share the xml and stacktrace

Comment: To Jerrol oh... my mistake, but it doesn't change anything. To John Joe where can I find the stacktrace? To Hi I'm Frogatto: yes from b1 to b9. To Godwin: one moment and I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

you said you have only **9** buttons and the name starts from b1-b9
while you are generating a number that is always greater or equal to than 10

```
public void buttonDisappear(Button view){
    shownButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Random generatedNumber = new Random();
    int buttonNumber = generatedNumber.nextInt(9)+1;
    String nextShownButton = "b"+String.valueOf(buttonNumber);
    int nextShownButtonId = getResources().getIdentifier(nextShownButton, "id", getPackageName());

    Button shownButton = (Button) findViewById(nextShownButtonId);
    shownButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

Comment: Nice catch! by the way, there's no need to cast return value of `findViewById` to `Button` merely for setting its visibility. `findViewById(nextShownButtonId).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` is enough.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto , That's correct , but casting doesn't let the app to stop

Comment: Yeah, your absolutely correct. But it's not necessary.

Comment: @Godwin Thank you for correction :) Just now I noticed my other mistake Button shownButton = (Button) findViewById(nextShownButtonId); should be changed into just shownButton = (Button) findViewById(nextShownButtonId);. And it works just fine. I shouldn't create two different button variables, just use one I've already created. Thank you all for help ^-^